# Apply function to each element of list recursion

Tags: python, recursion

I have a function that takes a keyword as input and returns a list of related keywords.
What I need is a function that will get the related keywords and then run again on each keyword on the returned list, and so on for a defined number of times.

```
def find_related(kw):

#magic happens

return related_kws

'''
Example:

>>>find_related('eat')
{
    'base_kw': 'eat'
    'related_kws': ['eat pasta', 'eat meat', 'eat fish']
}
'''
```

What I need is something like this:

```
def difficult_function(kw, cycles):

#cycles determines number of times to run recursion
#magic beyond my league happens...

return more_related_keywords

'''
EXAMPLE #1

>>>difficult_function('eat', 2)
{
    'base_kw': 'eat'
    'related_kws': {
        'eat pasta': ['eat cold pasta', 'eat italian pasta', 'eat instant pasta'],
        'eat meat': ['eat raw meat', 'eat cow meat', 'eat roasted meat'],
        'eat fish': ['eat raw fish', 'eat rotten fish', 'eat fresh fish']
    }
}

'''

'''
EXAMPLE #2

>>>difficult_function('eat', 3)
{
    'base_kw': 'eat'
    'related_kws': {
        'eat pasta': {
            'eat cold pasta': [
                'eat cold pasta with sauce',
                'eat cold pasta and wine',
                'eat cold pasta at night'
            ],
            'eat italian pasta': [
                'eat italian cheap pasta',
                'eat best italian pasta',
                'eat italian pasta and pesto'
            ],
            'eat instant pasta': [
                'eat instant pasta snack',
                'eat instant cheese pasta',
                'eat healthy instant pasta'
            ]
        },
        'eat meat': {
            'eat raw meat': [
                'eat raw meat dangerous',
                'eat raw chicken meat',
                'eat raw meat with lemon'
            ],
            'eat cow meat': [
                'eat cow meat and salad',
                'eat cow meat and rice,
                'eat cow meat benefits'
            ],
            'eat roasted meat': [
                'eat roasted meat sandwich',
                'eat cold roasted meat',
                'don\'t eat roasted meat'
            ]
        },
        'eat fish': {
            'eat raw fish': [
                'eat raw fish sushi',
                'eat raw fish health', 'eat raw fish japanese'],
            'eat rotten fish': [
                'eat rotten fish bacteria',
                'eat rotten fish death',
                'eat rotten fish stomach'
            ],
            'eat fresh fish': [
                'eat fresh fish restaurant',
                'eat fresh fish with lemon',
                'eat fresh fish at home']
        }
    }
}
'''
```

I know I'm supposed to share here what I already tried, but the truth is I don't even know where to begin. Any ideas?

EDIT:

The function below simulates the functioning of find_related(kw). My apologies if the question isn't presented in the appropiate way, I'm a total noob

```
import string
import random

def find_related(kw):
    # A lot of magic happens, the list comprehension
    # below simulates the magic
    related_kws = [
        kw + ' ' + ''.join(
            random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase) for 
            _ in range(4)) for i in range(3)
    ]

    results = {
        'base_kw': kw,
        'related_kws': related_kws
    }

    return results
```

---

Mock function that matches examples given.

```
def find_related(kw):
    '''mock function'''
    # A lot of magic happens, this simulates the magic
    d = {'eat': ['eat pasta', 'eat meat', 'eat fish'],
         'eat pasta': ['eat cold pasta', 'eat italian pasta', 'eat instant pasta'],
         'eat meat': ['eat raw meat', 'eat cow meat', 'eat roasted meat'],
         'eat fish': ['eat raw fish', 'eat rotten fish', 'eat fresh fish'],
         'eat cold pasta': ['eat cold pasta with sauce', 'eat cold pasta and wine', 'eat cold pasta at night'],
         'eat italian pasta': ['eat italian cheap pasta', 'eat best italian pasta', 'eat italian pasta and pesto'],
         'eat instant pasta': ['eat instant pasta snack', 'eat instant cheese pasta', 'eat healthy instant pasta'],
         'eat raw meat': ['eat raw meat dangerous', 'eat raw chicken meat', 'eat raw meat with lemon'],
         'eat cow meat': ['eat cow meat and salad', 'eat cow meat and rice', 'eat cow meat benefits'],
         'eat roasted meat': ['eat roasted meat sandwich', 'eat cold roasted meat', 'don\'t eat roasted meat'],
         'eat raw fish': ['eat raw fish sushi', 'eat raw fish health', 'eat raw fish japanese'],
         'eat rotten fish': ['eat rotten fish bacteria', 'eat rotten fish death', 'eat rotten fish stomach'],
         'eat fresh fish': ['eat fresh fish restaurant', 'eat fresh fish with lemon', 'eat fresh fish at home']

         }


    results = {
        'base_kw': kw,
        'related_kws': d[kw]
        }
```

Comment: I think we'll need a more complete problem specification to even lead you toward a solution.  Where do the added words come from?  There should be a ["cold", "Italian", "instant"] reference somewhere, information where it requires insertion, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It's a pretty large script that determines what are the related keywords, based on scraping, an internal database, etc. Basically, you pass it a kw and it will return a list of related kws. I'm editing the question to add a function that simulates the behavior of my current function

Comment: Also, the utter lack of code implies that you don't know how to iterate through your data structures, manipulate strings, etc.  This does not help your case for getting help.

Comment: The structure of the script's interface with your code is important to designing any solution.  You have one set of words to insert in the middle of the phrase, another set to append.  We have no idea what controls how far you go with the insertions, what sorts of insertions there are, etc.

Comment: Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.  Any code should follow the guidelines in [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: For very general hints (since this is still a very general problem), you'll want to look up the **map** function, and perhaps a couple of facilities of **itertools**.

Comment: You want to call ```find_related``` then call it again ```cycles``` times using the first ```cycles``` results from the first call?  Does it Have to be recursive?

Comment: @wwii yes to the first question and no, it doesn't have to be recursive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the answer in case someone is looking for something similar. Again my apologies if the question was poorly presented.

```
import pprint
import string
import random

def find_related(kw):
    # A lot of magic happens, the list comprehension
    # below simulates the magic
    related_kws = [
        kw + ' ' + ''.join(
            random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase) for 
            _ in range(4)) for i in range(3)
    ]
    results = {
        'base_kw': kw,
        'related_kws': related_kws
    }
    return results

def difficult_function(kw, cycles):    
    return {
        'base_kw': kw,
        'related_kws': rec_kw(kw, cycles)
    }

def rec_kw(kw, cycles):
    if cycles == 1:
        return find_related(kw)
    else:
        result = {}
        for k in find_related(kw)['related_kws']:
            result[k] = rec_kw(k, cycles-1)
        return result

pprint.pprint(difficult_function('eat', 3))
```

Answer (score 0):

This code do something you need. In order to see the results, I wrote it to work with global list INP, but there principle will work for you.

```
INP = ["Lorem", "Ipsum", "dolor", "atea"]

def recursive (kw, max, ref=None):

    ret = None
    if ref is None:
        ret = {'base_kw' : kw, 'related_kws' : {}}
        ref = ret ['related_kws']

    if max != 1:
        words = [' '.join (INP [0: len (INP) - max + 1]), ]
        for kw in words:
            ref [kw] = {}
            ref = ref [kw]
            recursive (kw, max -1, ref)
    else:
        ref [kw] = [' '.join (INP)]

    return ret

print (recursive ("Lorem", 3))
```

This is the output:

```
{'related_kws': {'Lorem Ipsum': {'Lorem Ipsum dolor': {'Lorem Ipsum dolor': ['Lorem Ipsum dolor atea']}}}, 'base_kw': 'Lorem'}
```